# probability density kernel / integral

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Does anyone know if the following

$$g(x) = \exp{(ax - b \exp{(cx)})}$$

(where $a,b,c$ are positive constants) is the kernel of any known probability distribution with support for all $\mathbb{R}$? It looks related to the Gumbel, but I can't find it anywhere.

Regardless, we would need to calculate $\int_\mathbb{R} g(x)dx$ as a function of $a,b,c$ and other fundamental constants.

If no one knows that, is there a way to prove that $\int_\mathbb{R} g(x)dx < \infty$ for certain $a,b,c$ values?

Comment: this diverges as ****